# setting up iphone 5s

Tags: iphone, setup

I set up my child's phone with my Apple ID.  Now all of the text messages come over with my name instead of her name.  Can I change this on the iphone without setting up an apple id for her?

Comment: No. AppleIDs are not meant to be shared. Use [Family Sharing](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201060) instead.

Comment: Since its your daughter I'll add use parental controls and family sharing to achieve your needs.  You're not the first parent in this situation instead of trying to be controlling via an id that's not meant to be shared, find out how the system was built with parent/child in mind.

Answer (score 1):

No. You have to set up an AppleID for her. If you want to share apps and music purchases, then you can use Family Sharing, and you can even specify if your child is able to purchase music/apps, or require you to approve the purchase first. This way, she is not able to rack up a huge bill, and you can both have separate messaging accounts.